# NGINX - mostrar 404 personalizado

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, nginx, apache2

Tengo configurado un servidor con Nginx y apache y tengo un problema para mostrar un 404 personalizado.

Tengo dos posibles URL's

http://factura.local/index.php?num_factura=F0001&**empresa=seur**
http://factura.local/index.php?num_factura=F0002&**empresa=mrw**

Dependiendo de un parámetro del query_string que es la empresa, quiero mostrar un error 404 o otro en caso de no existir la URL, para ello he probado esta configuración en nginx pero me da error de sintaxis.

```
if ($args ~ empresa=seur) {
   location = /404_seur.html {
       root /var/www/html/factura/errors;
       internal;
    }
else  {
   location = /404_mrw.html {
      root /var/www/html/factura/errors;
      internal;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

intenta con las siguientes lineas de código

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

error_page 404 /404.html; #aca va tu error personalizado
```

usa sudo `nginx -t` para que te diga si tienes errores antes que reinicies el nginx

Comment: Perfecto , era justo lo que buscava.